# Enterprise ipa on web install failled on iOS 10 which never installed the app

Tags: ios10, ipa

[image]

If the app had been installed on the device with iOS10 successfully once,then it can been installed anytime.But failed,if never been installed. Appreciate any  clues,TKS very much!

Comment: I meet the same problem, have you solve it now?

Comment: I export the IPA for incorrect type "Ad Hoc","Save for Enterprise  Deployment" instead solve it;